# How to stop cloud-init setting "Domains=" in networkd config?

Tags: systemd-networkd, systemd-resolved, cloud-init

I am using `cloud-init` on Debian with `networkd` for renderer and activator tasks.

Is there a way to stop `cloud-init` adding `Domains=` to the generated `systemd-networkd` config file ? i.e.

`cloud-init` presently generates a file containing:

```
[Network]
DHCP=no
DNS=$my_dns_ip_goes_here
Domains=example.com
```

What I want:

```
[Network]
DHCP=no
DNS=$my_dns_ip_goes_here
```

The problem with the default output is it propagates to the `/etc/resolv.conf` that is auto-generated by `systemd-resolved`, and I don't want a `search example.com` line in my `resolv.conf` either.